# ERROR at line : PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored. while creating/replacing package body. Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException

Tags: asp.net, oracle

As my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054154/error-at-line-pl-sql-sql-statement-ignored-while-creating-replacing-package) same thing is happening with another procedure in the package.

my repository code:

```
using (OracleConnection oracleConnection = new BaseRepository().Connection)
                {
                    oracleConnection.Open();
                    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("PACKAGE_ACCOUNT.USP_GET_USER_BY_CREDENTIALS", oracleConnection);
                    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    
                    command.Parameters.Add("SP_CURSOR", OracleDbType.RefCursor, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output);
                    command.Parameters.Add("SP_LOGIN_NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50, loginName, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
                    command.Parameters.Add("SP_LOGIN_PASSWORD", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50, Security.EncryptText(loginPassword), System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
                    
                    Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, ApplicationUser>();
                    dataReader = command.ExecuteReader(); // exception arises here.

                   List<ApplicationUser> lstUsers = Mapper.Map<List<ApplicationUser>>(dataReader);
                    return lstUsers.FirstOrDefault();
                }
```

my package specification :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PACKAGE_ACCOUNT
AS
TYPE T_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
PROCEDURE USP_GET_APP_FUNC_BY_ROLE_ID(SP_ROLE_ID IN INT, SP_CURSOR OUT T_CURSOR);
END PACKAGE_ACCOUNT;
/
```

my package body :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PACKAGE_ACCOUNT
AS 

PROCEDURE USP_GET_APP_FUNC_BY_ROLE_ID(SP_ROLE_ID IN INT, SP_CURSOR OUT T_CURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN SP_CURSOR FOR
select "ApplicationFunction".* from "RoleAccess"
Inner Join "ApplicationFunction" 
on "RoleAccess"."fkApplicationFunctionId" = "ApplicationFunction"."pkApplicationFunctionId"
Where "RoleAccess"."fkApplicationRoleId" = SP_ROLE_ID;
END USP_GET_APP_FUNC_BY_ROLE_ID;


END PACKAGE_ACCOUNT;
/
```

This time the same error is at (select "ApplicationFunction".* ).
Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PACKAGE_ACCOUNT
AS
TYPE T_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
PROCEDURE USP_GET_APP_FUNC_BY_ROLE_ID(SP_ROLE_ID IN NUMBER(10,0), SP_CURSOR OUT T_CURSOR);
END PACKAGE_ACCOUNT;
```

there no `INT` in ORACLE change it to `NUMBER(10,0)` hope this will solve your problem.